# Can adjectives assign thematic roles in English (or other languages)?

Tags: parts-of-speech, thematic-roles

Example: *The dog was very excited* or *he was a very excited dog*

Does *excited* assign the role of experiencer to dog in either case?

Do adjectives assign them in other languages?

Or would we say that participials can assign roles and that they don't really fit into any word class.

Comment: Yes, adjectives assign thematic roles, some more than one. The example _He washed the nervous dog_ is indeed such that _the dog_ receives two thematic roles, one from the matrix predicate _washed_ and one from the embedded predicate _nervous_. There is a difference across these two predicates, though, the matrix predicate being a matter of assertion, and the embedded predicate a matter of presupposition.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in "The dog was very excited" you could talk about an Experiencer triggered by an adjective regardless of its participial origin or not (replace "nervous" above). Some might object that this semantic role should be reserved to humans, but that's not relevant here. Semantic roles are usually licensed by verbs, but in this case it's the adjective that does the job since the copula is a semantic dummy.
However, the only role I can envisage with adjective+copula is that of Experiencer or at the very maximum that of a Theme, as in: "The man was dead"

Comment: Ok so in the clause *He washed the nervous dog*, can *dog* be assigned two semantic roles?

Comment: No, in this case the dog is a Patient.

Comment: But is the dog also not an experiencer?

Comment: Not in this case. An entity cannot cover two roles at the same time. Here, the dog "gets washed". You could also say it's an Undergoer rather than a Patient. The fact that the dog is nervous does not play any role.

Comment: This may be why e.g. French postpones adjectives? *He washed the dog [who was] nervous*; *He: washes; the dog: nervous*. This is further underligned by Ger *da* creating various relative clauses, as a precourser of the definite article. Also cp *he washed the dog [that [it] got] nervous*. I am becoming kinda nervous!

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with it. Semantic roles are determined by the verb. If you need some links about the topic, I'll be glad to post them.

Comment: Why can't a noun phrase have two semantic roles? It seems counter-intuitive here.

Comment: You have been suspended again....You have to keep a low profile if you really want to use SE sites.

Comment: @Mr.Black Do we know each other?

Comment: since *nervous* is a loan, and *-s* can be verb marker in principle , I'd argue that it could be deemed a participle, intuitively. E.g., the *-n* in *green* (cp. *grow*, Ger. *es grünt*), the *-nce* in *bronce* and perhaps the *-en* in *golden* (see there, cp. *vergoldet*), might reflect the same. Other than that, no more objections.